# Problems with building ros packages

Tags: ros, stack, rosmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am new to linux and the ros operating system and I am trying to build the ros packages with diamondback but I am having a lot of trouble. For when I invoke $rosmake mini_max , I build most of the packages but I get a message that says that some of the stacks failed to load and one of the packages aren't built. The following below is what I get:

karl@ubuntu:~$ rosmake mini_max
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['mini_max']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/karl/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111001-143339
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['mini_max'] to:
['mini_max_apps', 'mini_max_tutorials', 'mini_max_defs']
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages mini_max.  This may take a few seconds.
Failed to find stack for package [arm_navigation_msgs]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [arm_navigation_msgs]:Cannot locate installation of package arm_navigation_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [arm_navigation_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/karl/ros:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
Failed to find stack for package [arm_navigation_msgs]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [arm_navigation_msgs]:Cannot locate installation of package arm_navigation_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [arm_navigation_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/karl/ros:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> actionlib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package trajectory_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< actionlib ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tinyxml [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbagmigration [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbagmigration ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbagmigration
No Makefile in package rosbagmigration
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tinyxml ROS_NOBUILD in package tinyxml
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> control_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< control_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package control_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xacro [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xacro ROS_NOBUILD in package xacro
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> mini_max_apps [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> ivcon [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< ivcon ROS_NOBUILD in package ivcon
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> angles [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosnode [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosnode ROS_NOBUILD in package rosnode
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
No Makefile in package rosmsg
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostopic [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostopic ROS_NOBUILD in package rostopic
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roswtf ROS_NOBUILD in package roswtf
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> arbotix_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< mini_max_apps [PASS] [ 8.87 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nav_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package nav_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_srvs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_srvs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> app_manager [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< app_manager ROS_NOBUILD in package app_manager
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> turtlebot_driver [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< turtlebot_driver ROS_NOBUILD in package turtlebot_driver
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> eigen [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< eigen ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> turtlebot_node [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< turtlebot_node ROS_NOBUILD in package turtlebot_node
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> turtlebot_description [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< turtlebot_description ROS_NOBUILD in package turtlebot_description
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> diagnostic_updater [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< diagnostic_updater ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_updater
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> joy [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< joy ROS_NOBUILD in package joy
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> kdl_parser [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kdl_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl_parser
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf_conversions [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package tf_conversions
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> robot_state_publisher [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< robot_state_publisher ROS_NOBUILD in package robot_state_publisher
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cminpack [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cminpack ROS_NOBUILD in package cminpack
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> flann [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< flann ROS_NOBUILD in package flann
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pointcloud_to_laserscan [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pointcloud_to_laserscan ROS_NOBUILD in package pointcloud_to_laserscan
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> stereo_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< stereo_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package stereo_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> openni [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< openni ROS_NOBUILD in package openni
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> openni_camera [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< openni_camera ROS_NOBUILD in package openni_camera
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> compressed_image_transport [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< compressed_image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package compressed_image_transport
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> turtlebot_bringup [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< turtlebot_bringup ROS_NOBUILD in package turtlebot_bringup
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> simple_arm_server [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< arbotix_msgs [PASS] [ 9.49 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> arbotix_python [ make ]
[ rosmake ] All 25 linesimple_arm_server: 0.3 sec... [ 2 Active 80/89 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
-- Action Files:MoveArm.action
-- Generating Messages for ActionMoveArm.action
-- /home/karl/ros/vanadium-ros-pkg/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/msg/MoveArmAction.msg
[rosbuild] Building package simple_arm_server
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests simple_arm_server
[rospack] couldn't find dependency [arm_navigation_msgs] of [simple_arm_server]
[rospack] missing dependency

CMake Error at /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:113 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
'simple_arm_server'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.
Please fix the broken dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:183 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:16 (rosbuild_init)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package simple_arm_server written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/karl/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111001-143339/simple_arm_server/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< simple_arm_server [FAIL] [ 0.36 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package simple_arm_server.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< arbotix_python [PASS] [ 5.81 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 82 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/karl/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111001-143339

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11386/problems-with-building-ros-packages/) by [applecrusher](https://answers.ros.org/users/1150/applecrusher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-10-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you don't have `arm_navigation_msgs` installed, which is a dependency of `mini_max`. You'll have to install the `arm_navigation` stack before building `mini_max`.

`arm_navigation_msgs` is a new package in Electric, so you'll also have to upgrade to ROS Electric from Diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [applecrusher](https://answers.ros.org/users/1150/applecrusher/) on 2011-10-03**:
Thank you very much